# MySQL: Transport planner with repeating tasks

Tags: php, mysql, frequency, project-planning

I'm working on a transport planner. My MySQL(i)/PHP knowledge is (very) basic.

I want to display a HTML table with all tasks of a certain day.
But the problem is that some tasks need to be repeated (until I delete the whole task) so the tasks have a frequency like: once, daily, weekly, two-weekly and monthly.

So ofcourse, when i'm adding a new task on monday with a weekly frequency, that task have to return in my table every monday.

Should I combine something like:

```
SELECT * FROM planner 
         WHERE frequency = `once` 
         AND date = CURDATE()

SELECT * FROM planner 
         WHERE frequency = `daily/weekly/two-weekly/monthly/yearly` 
         AND day = DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE())
         AND date + INTERVAL 1 DAY/1 WEEK/2 WEEK/1 MONTH
```

And if so, how then?

Hope someone can help me.

**EDIT:**

For once, daily and weekly tasks a query like this (probably still horrible) will do:

```
(SELECT *
        FROM planner 
        WHERE frequency = 'once' 
        AND date = NOW())
UNION
(SELECT *
        FROM planner 
        WHERE frequency = 'daily' 
        AND date + INTERVAL 1 DAY)
UNION
(SELECT *
        FROM planner
        WHERE frequency = 'weekly' 
        AND day = DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()) 
        AND date + INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
```

Although, for 'two-weekly' and 'monthly' INTERVAL + 2 WEEK / 1 MONTH, will return results **every** week. How to fix this?

**EDIT:**

I don't use validity colums in my table because I wasn't aware of expired/invalid past tasks. I changed my laptop year to 2040 and there was a mysql error indeed. I've changed plans and I think it's better that repeating task are valid one year, with the option to delete or to extend for another year. Then also I forgot to mention that when I create a task on monday with a monthly frecuency, that the task return in my table the first monday of the next month. Also the tasks with the 'once' frequency appear every day in my table when I try your solution.

**EDIT**

@SparKot, usual with a monthly frequency the task is viewed on, example, 2013-03-05 and the next time would be 2013-04-05, 2013-05-05 and so on.
Although in this planner a monthly task set on example, tuesday 2013-03-05 should reappear on the first tuesday of the next month (april: 2013-04-02, may: 2013-05-07, june: 2013-06-04).

Comment: don't you have validity period for `repeating tasks`? What if you forget to delete invalid tasks? Please share table schema, `show create table planner`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming there are validity columns in table:

```
SELECT *
  FROM planner
 WHERE     now() >= valid_from
       AND now() <= valid_to
       AND (frequency = 'daily'
            OR (frequency = 'once' AND date(now()) = date)
            OR (frequency = 'weekly' AND 0 = (abs(datediff(now(), date)) % 7))
            OR (frequency = 'two-weekly' AND 0 = (abs(datediff(now(), date)) % 14))
            OR (frequency = 'monthly' 
                AND ceil(dayofmonth(now())/7) = ceil(dayofmonth(date)/7)
                AND dayofweek(now()) = dayofweek(date))
            );
```

Without validity columns: you might get expired/invalid past tasks which are not yet deleted:

```
SELECT *
  FROM planner
 WHERE (frequency = 'daily'
            OR (frequency = 'once' AND date(now()) = date)
            OR (frequency = 'weekly' AND 0 = (abs(datediff(now(), date)) % 7))
            OR (frequency = 'two-weekly' AND 0 = (abs(datediff(now(), date)) % 14))
            OR (frequency = 'monthly' 
                AND ceil(dayofmonth(now())/7) = ceil(dayofmonth(date)/7)
                AND dayofweek(now()) = dayofweek(date))
            );
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @SparKot! I don't use validity colums in my table because I wasn't aware of expired/invalid past tasks. I changed my laptop year to 2040 and there was a mysql error indeed. I've changed plans and I think it's better that repeating task are valid one year, with the option to delete or to extend for another year.

Comment: @user2131419 First question here, please read what to do [when you get answers](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).

Comment: `once` frequency should be fixed now. What's wrong with `monthly` frequency?

Comment: It should be ok now as per your `monthly` frequency definition.

Comment: Is it possible to customize your solution query so that tasks won't be displayed on saturdays and sundays, if possible?